# Get index of list within list in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

If I have a list like this

```
((0 1 2) (3 4 5) (6 7 8) (0 3 6) (1 3 7) (2 4 8) (0 4 8) (2 4 6))
```

And I want to find the index of `(0 3 6)`, is there a built-in function to do this? `POSITION` doesn't seem to work when the search item is itself a list.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_pos_p.htm). POSITION can take a `:test` argument:

```
(position '(0 3 6)
          '((0 1 2) (3 4 5) (6 7 8) (0 3 6) (1 3 7) (2 4 8) (0 4 8) (2 4 6))
          :test #'equal))
3
```

The default test for POSITION (and other sequence operations) is EQL, by the way.

Comment: Curiously, the CLHS page for FIND links to "Rules about Test Functions", but the page for POSITION doesn't.  Here's where the default of `EQL` is documented: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/17_ba.htm

Comment: sorry but which language should i choose in DrRacket to run this code @Nietzche-jou